# $\sigma$ algebra as sheaf and what is its direct image?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, sheaf-theory

Let $X$ be a measurable space.(i.e. $X$ is equipped with sigma algebra $R$.) Furthermore, note that $R$ really defines a sheaf of sigma algebra via $R\cap U$ for any open $U\subset X$ where intersection is obvious choice on elements.) $f:X\to Y$ is a measurable map. Then $f_\star R=\{E\subset Y\vert f^{-1}(E)\in R\}$ defines sigma algebra on $Y$ which also forms a sheaf.

$\textbf{Q:}$ Since this looks like pushing forward the sheaf, I would certainly hope there is inverse image functor $f^{-1}$.(i.e. $f:X\to Y$ as "morphism" s.t. $Y$ is equipped with some $\sigma$ algebra $R_Y$ with $f^{-1}(R_Y)$ defines sigma algebra over $X$.) However, in algebraic geometric setting, I need sheafification procedure going on. It seems that I do not need it here? I want to say $f^{-1}(R_Y)=\{f^{-1}(U)|U\in R_Y\}$ defines $\sigma$ algebra over $X$ Is this even correct?

Comment: Your $f^{-1}(R_{Y})$ is of course a $\sigma$-algebra on $X$, but I can't understand how you view $R$ as a sheaf on $X$. If I understood correctly, on each open set $U$, the set of elements in $R$ that are contained in $U$ is the object assigned on $U$. But... then given an open cover $U_{i}$, how can you find a measurable set by putting measurable subsets of $U_{i}$ all together, when there are uncountably many $U_{i}$'s?

Comment: @JunekeyJeon I probably assume that $R$ is contains Borel algebra. Then one can take intersection of $R\cap U$ for any $U$ open in $X$.

Comment: Yeah, I see that. But I'm talking about gluing condition.

Comment: @JunekeyJeon For uncountably many $U_i$'s part, I think one might need some sort of countability condition. I am not sure whether sigma compact argument passes through here.

Comment: Okay, then why don't we assume $X$ is second countable?

Comment: @JunekeyJeon In that case, it is indeed the sheaf. And both inverse image and direct image are fine. Thanks.